# OpenSSL verify certificate from own CA

Tags: ruby, openssl, x509certificate2

Hello all and thanks for your time reading this.

I need to verify certificates issued by my own CA, for which I have a
certificate. How can I do the equivalent to openssl's

openssl verify -CAfile

in Ruby code? The RDoc for OpenSSL is not very helpful in this regard.
I've tried:

```
require 'openssl'

ca = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.read('ca-cert.pem'))

lic = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.read('cert.pem'))

puts lic.verify( ca )
```

but I get:

```
test.rb:7:in `verify': wrong argument (OpenSSL::X509::Certificate)!
(Expected kind of OpenSSL::PKey::PKey) (TypeError)
  from test.rb:7
```

I can't even find "verify" in the OpenSSL Rdoc at
http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/index.html.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks again!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to validate with

```
lic.verify(ca.public_key)
```

in addition before that you can verify certificate issuer with

```
lic.issuer.to_s == ca.subject.to_s
```

I used one [Japanese help page](http://doc.loveruby.net/refm/api/view/class/OpenSSL=X509=Certificate) to get the list of available methods :)

Answer (score 2):

`lic.verify()` only verify the key from the certificate that signed lic. Ccommercial root CAs do not sign end user certificates directly. Usually there is one or 2 intermediate signing certificates involved.

So if `CA -> signer -> user cert` then

`lic.verify( signer.public_key)` and `signer.verify( CA.public_key)` will return true but `lic.verify( CA.public_key )` will return false.