# How to access client X.509 certificate from Ruby web service (not Rails)?

Tags: ruby, web-services, certificate, sinatra, rack

How can I access the client X.509 certificate from a Ruby web service? The client is passing a client certificate, and it's fine that the browser is authenticating that for me, but I also want to look at the certificate in my Ruby code.

This is not Rails. I'm looking for an answer using Sinatra, for example. And, from a web server such as nginx or lighttpd.

Comment: Having you written anything, or are you just hoping for someone to have a working sample? We expect you to show what you've searched, and why it didn't help, or the code you've written and why it's not working.

Comment: I'd look into Openssl for a validation function.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14173354/how-to-mimic-browser-x509-client-certificate-verification-without-access-to-http. As stated there, the Nginx/Apache server will take care of this. In its configuration maybe you could do something to pass those headers on and then use OpenSSL (or something) to handle the certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an Apache web server listening on port 443 with SSL configured, as a reverse proxy to a Thin server running a Sinatra app, for example, I can add these to my Apache VirtualHost configuration:

```
RequestHeader set SSL-Client-M-Serial %{SSL_CLIENT_M_SERIAL}s
RequestHeader set SSL-Client-S-DN %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN}s 
RequestHeader set SSL-Client-I-DN %{SSL_CLIENT_I_DN}s
```

Then from my Sinatra code, I can find these values in the Rack environment, for example:

```
puts "#{request.env['HTTP_SSL_CLIENT_S_DN']}"
```

I don't have the full client certificate, which is OK since I'm having Apache verify the certificate.