# Error in Heroku while running Sinatra app

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra, webrick

I have a Sinatra app using Webrick as its webserver(i know i should be using unicorn :)) , I am deploying it on Heroku and I am getting the following error on entering the url.

```
2013-10-26T01:28:04.463156+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=bbb-enroll.herokuapp.com fwd="67.188.115.197" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-10-26T01:28:04.565142+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=bbb-enroll.herokuapp.comfwd="67.188.115.197" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-10-26T01:28:10.665271+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=bbb-enroll.herokuapp.com fwd="67.188.115.197" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

The compile goes through fine, but the url does not open and the `heroku logs` command shows the errors. 
This is my `config.ru` file

```
require './application'
run Sinatra::Application
```

and this is my application.rb file

```
... require code .....

webrick_options = {
        :Port               => 8443,
        :Logger             => WEBrick::Log::new($stderr, WEBrick::Log::DEBUG),
        :DocumentRoot       => "/ruby/htdocs",
        #:DoNotReverseLookup => false,
        :SSLEnable          => true,
        :SSLVerifyClient    => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE,
        :SSLCertificate     => IOSCertEnrollment::SSL.certificate,
        :SSLPrivateKey      => IOSCertEnrollment::SSL.key,
        :SSLCertName        => [ [ "CN",WEBrick::Utils::getservername ] ]
}

.//lots of code....
.....
class NBServer  < Sinatra::Base
...//lots of code//...
..
Rack::Handler::WEBrick.run NBServer, webrick_options
```

What am I doing wrong! ?

Comment: Actually, you should be using Puma :) I'm guessing you're using Webrick to get access to those SSL options? Maybe it's because [the SSL headers aren't passed through](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14174600/335847)